# updating dat.gui based on selected object

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

[current working code](http://jsfiddle.net/yeehawjared/c36pt/5/)

I'm trying to figure out how to update/change/refresh dat.gui to reflect my current selection.  My goal is to generate some random cubes and then select a single cube for manipulation like: rotate, scale, change position, etc.

The first step is being able to select a cube and being able to control something, anything from dat.gui.  In the example below, I simply want to display the name of the selected object.  I feel like If I solve that, I can add methods to control rotation, position, etc.

[I am trying to achieve something like this](http://fhtr.org/BasicsOfThreeJS/#44), but this code is old and hard to understand.

```
controller = new THREE.Object3D();
controller.objects = [];
controller.scene = scene;
controller.gui = gui;
controller.color = 0xFFFFFF;
controller.number_of_objects = controller.objects.length;
controller.selected_cube = 'test123';


controller.createNew = function() {
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
            opacity: 0.5})
    );

    cube.position.x = Math.random() * (world_size * 2) - world_size;
    cube.position.z = Math.random() * (world_size * 2) - world_size;
    cube.name = 'cube_' + controller.objects.length;

    controller.scene.add(cube);
    controller.objects.push(cube);
    controller.number_of_objects = controller.objects.length;
    controller.selected_cube = cube.name;

};

gui.add(controller, 'number_of_objects').listen();
gui.add(controller, 'selected_cube').listen();
gui.add(controller, 'createNew');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've forked your example and added code so that the selected cube gets shown in the dat.GUI control:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/5vbkub4v/

The code to achieve this is here:

```
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        var selectedObject = intersects[0].object;
        selectedObject.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);

        // listen() has already been applied to the dat.GUI selected_cube controller
        // so updating the value of selected_cube will cause the dat.GUI view
        // to be automatically updated.
        controller.selected_cube = selectedObject.name;

        var particle = new THREE.Sprite(particleMaterial);
        particle.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
        particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 2;
        scene.add(particle);
    }
```

This works because as:

```
gui.add(controller, 'selected_cube').listen();
```

has already been defined, changing the value of dat.GUI selected_cube variable would automatically 
be reflected in the control panel.

Comment: But you are not really changing the object that GUI is pointing to to resolve its property, you are just changing one property directly with your example. How could you use this to e.g. modify the X,Y,Z position or any other property of the selected object in the 3d scene? It seems some kind of proxy object would have to be made for this?